# Django Cookiecutter: How to import AUTH_USER_MODEL in config/settings/base.py?

Tags: django, cookiecutter-django

As we know, Django-Cookiecutter has a different setup for settings files. The regular *from django.conf import settings* doesn't work here.

I want to reference to the custom user model defined in the base.py file in the settings directory. Any ideas?

Below is my project layout:

```
repository/
    config/
        settings/
            __init__.py
            base.py # where the auth_user_model variable is defined
            local.py
            production.py
            test.py
    app_dir/
        users/
            __init__.py
            models.py # where the custom user model is stored
```

I also tried to import the custom user model directly from users/models.py as below:

```
from users.models import User
```

But got the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Model class users.models.User doesn't declare an 
explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried the following, and it seems to work so far:

```
from config.settings.base import AUTH_USER_MODEL
```

Comment: A related change I had to make in my tests was to use absolute import paths instead of relative paths. e.g from ..views import (...) gave me the same runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
```

It'll return django user class that you defined in base.py

**Edit:**

```
from django.conf.settings import AUTH_USER_MODEL
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using Django 1.10. I think there's still a difference b/w get_user_model and AUTH_USER_MODEL, somehow? I'm trying to reference the current User model in another model, so maybe using  AUTH_USER_MODEL is better.

Comment: I think you should read django documentation. I added that code is standart code of django. django.conf.settings have all vars value of settings dir.